# What to do with students after templates were explained?

Tags: c++

I'm having a C++ seminar in 30 minutes :-)

Because I incorporated most of the examples I usually do on the seminar into the lecture I don't have anything to do with my students. I just gave them a broad overview of templates (from basics to advanced topics).

Any tips what to do?

It can be something that I will explain (step-by-step), or something they will have to code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replicate containers - like a list or a vector.

Comment: Yeah, that's my backup idea :-)

Comment: I ended up with a double linked list. Worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to implement templates that mirror or are similar to those currently in the STL?

It will give them practice in developing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can challenge them with a "can-be-a-real-system"... and ask them what possible best-practices...

Answer (score 0):

Once you've delivered the basics of templates, point them in the direction of the standard template library and have them get their head around using std::list, std::vector etc to store arrays of objects and iterate through them.

It's easier to implement your own template code, once you understand their advantages.  So using the STL should be their next step.

After that, point them at boost ;)

Comment: They are using STL for several weeks already. This is about writing templated code.

Comment: Great stuff.  As others have said, have them write a linked list for generic types.  It's a thorough exercise in coding and in the use of templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet covered the STL, you could introduce them to that. It is a good example of why templates are extremely useful.

You could also introduce them to iterators using this approach. IMO, learning the STL is one of the most useful things you can learn in C++ :-)